# ¿Para que sirven los arreglos dinámicos con punteros?

Tags: c++

Entiendo como funcionan los arreglos dinámicos usando punteros, pero lo que he leído es que no se puede hacer esto sin ellos, pero a mi si me ha funcionado. ¿Hay algo que este ignorando? Ejemplos:
Arreglo dinámico con punteros:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int *notas, numero;

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de notas: ";
    cin>>numero;

    notas = new int[numero] ;

    for(int i=0; i<=numero-1; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese la nora "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>notas[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=numero-1; i++){
        cout<<notas[i]<<endl;
    }

    delete [] notas;

    return 0;
}
```

Pero esto también lo puedo hacer así:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int numero;

    cout<<"Ingrese el numero de notas: ";
    cin>>numero;

    int notas[numero];

    for(int i=0; i<=numero-1; i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese la nora "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>notas[i];
    }

    for(int i=0; i<=numero-1; i++){
        cout<<notas[i]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Mis preguntas son**

1. ¿Por qué funciona sin punteros?
2. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer para aumentar el tamaño del arreglo en ejecución, por ejemplo el usuario mete 3 notas, y poner un  menú que diga "Agregar mas notas" y hacer mas grande el arreglo?

Comment: Edité mi respuesta, ya que no era correcta. Así que le pido disculpa por hacerlo confundir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > ¿Para que sirven los arreglos dinámicos con punteros?

Un simple arreglo dinámico es un bloque de memoria que contiene elementos y para poder acceder a esos `elementos` se necesita de un puntero.

> > ¿Por qué funciona sin punteros?

Cualquiera pensaría que el segundo código si o si funcionaba gracias a los punteros a nivel de implementación. Pero esto no es del todo cierto y esto se debe porque el identificador `notas` no es traducido como un puntero, es decir, el compilador no necesitas reservar memoria para poder guardar la dirección base del array. Y esto lo comprobamos de esta manera:

```cpp
int numero;
cout<<"Ingrese el numero de notas: ";
cin>>numero;
int notas[numero];
printf("%p = %p\n", &notas, notas);
```

El resultado por pantalla es la dirección base del array y no del puntero en si y esto se debe porque `notas` simplemente es un alias que representa la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del array.

Por lo tanto, en el primer código cuando haces esto:

```cpp
int* notas = new int[numero];
*(notas + 0) = 10;
```

El identificador `notas` si es un puntero y por ende, para poder escribir el número `10` hacia la dirección base del array se necesita:

- Acceder al contenido del puntero y obtener la dirección base.
- Posteriormente, se le suma a la dirección base obtenida el [offset](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(inform%C3%A1tica)) necesario para llegar a la dirección de memoria de X elemento del array.
- Por último, accedemos al contenido de dicha dirección calculada.

Sin embargo, en el segundo código:

```cpp
int notas[numero];
*(notas + 0) = 10;
```

Es diferente. Puesto que solo debemos sumar a la dirección base el [offset](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(inform%C3%A1tica)) necesario para llegar a X dirección y con eso basta, por ende, no necesitamos acceder al contenido de un puntero, porque en si, el compilador no traduce `notas` como un puntero.

Entendiendo esto podemos responder a tu pregunta nuevamente:

> > ¿Por qué funciona sin punteros?

Funciona sin punteros porque en el segundo código, el símbolo `notas` es una simple **representación de la dirección base del array**, por lo tanto, no necesita de un puntero implícito para poder acceder a los elementos de un array, tal como pasa en el primer código.

También **recalco** que los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length array) no fueron introducidos en C++. Los compiladores gcc/g++ suelen tener soporte para declarar arreglos con longitud variable, sin embargo, harás que el código no sea portable. Además no necesitas usar los VLA, simplemente usa memoria dinámica.

> > ¿Como le puedo hacer para aumentar el tamaño del arreglo en ejecución, por ejemplo el usuario mete 3 notas, y poner un menú que diga "Agregar mas notas" y hacer mas grande el arreglo?

Con la clase [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) no necesitas preocuparte en aumentar el tamaño del arreglo.

**Ejemplo:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::vector<int> notas;
    notas.push_back(10);
    notas.push_back(12);
    notas.push_back(13);
    for(int nota : notas)
    {
        std::cout << nota << std::endl;
    }
    /*
       Resultado por pantalla:
       10
       12
       13
    */
    return 0;
}
```

**Fuente:**

- https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c#id5

Comment: Puntualización: el ejemplo puesto al final no corresponde a C++ clásico, sino a una versión más reciente de C++. Es posible (e intuyo que el autor de esta pregunta usa DevCpp) que si pones este código no te funcione porque no tenga soporte para esta versión de C++.

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos ¡Ups! Si, los for basado en rangos se introdujeron en C++11. El compilador de C++ de DevCpp (usando su última versión) por defecto compila con el estándar C++98. Así que toca compilar con la opción: `-std=c++11`.

Comment: O recomendar que se olvide el usuario de aprender con IDEs obsoletos y aunar esfuerzos en que no adquiera vicios de programación, pero quizás eso sería mucho pedir

Comment: No, *un array (arreglo) no es un puntero*. Por eso es necesario poner un asterisco delante para obtener el valor del primer miembro del array.

Comment: @JL.Sanchez Nunca dije que un array es un puntero. Cuando escribes esta línea: `int notas[10];` le dices al compilador: *Hey, reservarme una región de memoria con un tamaño de 10 elementos*, nada más. Sin embargo, el identificador `notas` sigue siendo un puntero. Así es como funciona internamente.

Comment: @MrDave1999 no, no es correcto. `notas[10]` no es un puntero, es un array. `sizeof(notas)` devolverá el tamaño de diez enteros, no el tamaño de un puntero. `int *notas` es una variable con espacio para almacenar una dirección; tras hacer `new` almacenará la dirección del bloque de 10 enteros creado.

Comment: @JL.Sanchez A nivel de sintaxis de C es válido lo que dices. Puesto tiene varias diferencias entre definir `int notas[10]` y `int* notas`, sin embargo, eso es a **nivel de sintaxis**. El compilador usa una tabla de símbolos y sabe que significa cada identificador (si es un array, puntero, función, etc.). Pero todo esto al compilador simplemente le sirve para poder **cumplir la sintaxis de C**, de lo contrario, da error. Sin embargo, en la etapa de la traducción, `notas` es traducido como un **puntero**.

Comment: @JL.Sanchez En fin, el OP no quiere saber la diferencia entre un array y un puntero a nivel de sintaxis de C, él lo que quiere es comprender la implementación (como lo lee la CPU).

Comment: @JL.Sanchez Gracias por su comentario, he editado mi respuesta para no traer mas confusiones.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias diferencias entre

```
int notas[numero];
```

y

```
notas = new int[numero];
```

Para este caso, la diferencia más significativa es que la primera variable es *automática*. Se crea dentro de un ámbito, se aloja en la pila (`stack`) y se destruye automáticamente al salir del ámbito de creación.

La segunda variable, en cambio, sí es *dinámica*, se aloja en el montículo (`heap`) y no será destruida hasta que explícitamente se llame a la función `delete`.

Una implicación importante de lo anterior es que en el primer caso, el array no se podrá usar fuera de la función en que fue creado, pero en el segundo caso sí.