# ¿Cómo leer un arreglo bidimensional usando punteros? C

Tags: c, punteros, array-bidimensional, scanf

Soy nuevo en esto de los punteros bidimensionales, estoy intentando leer un arreglo bidimensional mediante punteros usando esta lógica de arreglo unidimensional:

```
void leer(int *a){

int i;
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    printf("\nIngresa el valor [%d]\t",i);
    scanf("%d",(a+i));
}
printf("\n\tTermino la lectura\n");}
```

¿Cómo lo puedo representar en el scanf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo leer un arreglo bidimensional usando punteros? C

¡Necesitas usar aritmética de puntero!

La forma para acceder al contenido de un *array* bidimensional es usando aritmética de puntero. Es más, el compilador lo usa de forma implícita.

**Ejemplo:**

```c
int i = 1, j = 1;
int a[2][2];
a[i][j] = 10;
```

En este caso para poder asignar el número `10` en una determinada columna de la matriz, el compilador deberá  traducir el código `a[i][j]` de esta forma:

```c
*(a + i * 2 * sizeof(int) + j * sizeof(int)) = 10
```

Para explicar esta aritmética imaginemos que la matriz se refleja así en memoria:

```c
//Direcciones de memoria:

col0  col1

0x4   0x8  //-> fila 0

0x12  0x16 //-> fila 1
```

Esta expresión:

```c
a + i * 2 * sizeof(int)
```

Es la que nos permite acceder a la dirección base (la del primer elemento) de cada fila.

Entonces, si `i = 1`, debemos multiplicar el tamaño de columnas de la matriz por el tamaño de bytes que ocupa cada elemento del *array* bidimensional y al final sumar el resultado con la dirección que haga referencia `a` (que básicamente es un alias de la dirección del primer elemento del *array* 2D). Al evaluar nos queda esto:

```c
0x4 + 1 * 2 * 4 =
0x4 + 8 =
0x12
```

Interesante, nos dio la dirección `0x12`, claro esta corresponde al primer elemento de la segunda fila. Sin embargo, si sumamos el resultado de la anterior expresión por el resultado de esta expresión (claro asumiendo que `j = 1`):

```c
j * sizeof(int)

1 * 4 =
> 4
```

Nos da como resultado la dirección `0x16` y justamente esta es la dirección que necesitamos para poder asignarle el número `10`.

Entonces, ¿para que nos sirve todo esto?

Pues para responder esta pregunta:

> > ¿Cómo leer un arreglo bidimensional usando punteros? C

El código quedaría así:

```c
void leer(int * a)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            printf("\nIngresa el valor [%d,%d]\t", i, j);
            scanf("%d", a + i* M + j);
        }
    }
}
```

Y la forma de invocar la función sería así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3 //Cantidad de filas
#define M 4 //Cantidad de columnas

void leer(int*);

int main()
{
    int m[2][2] = 
    {
        {1, 5},
        {10, 5}
    };
    leer((int*)m);
    return 0;
}
```

Recorrer el *array* bidimensional a través de un puntero simple es tedioso, porque debes usar aritmética de puntero manualmente e incluso, el compilador gcc da una advertencia en esta línea:

```c
leer((int*)m);
```

Por esa razón le hice un *casting* para engañar al compilador, ya que recomienda que declare el parámetro de la función `leer` de esta forma:

```c
void leer(int[][M]);
```

Claro, al declarar de esta manera el parámetro no necesitamos usar aritmética de puntero porque el compilador lo hace de forma implícita.

Por esa razón, sería más seguro si recorres el *array* bidimensional de esta forma:

```c
void leer(int a[][M])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            printf("\nIngresa el valor [%d,%d]\t", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Actualización**

Respondiendo a esta pregunta:

> > ¿En la traducción a puntero *(a + i * 2 * sizeof(int) + j * sizeof(int)) = 10, el valor de a es 0?

El identificador `a` solo es un alias (esto es para poderlo identificar de una mejor manera) de la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del *array* bidimensional. En nuestro ejemplo que habíamos propuesto anteriormente, sería la dirección `0x4`.

```c
//Direcciones de memoria:

col0  col1

0x4   0x8  //-> fila 0

0x12  0x16 //-> fila 1
```

En este ejemplo, `a` es un alias de la dirección `0x4`.

> > ¿Para la dirección [0][0] del arreglo, sería el 0 en la cadena de dirección de memoria?

Si tuviéramos una sentencia así:

```c
a[0][0] = 10;
```

Sería traducido de esta forma:

```c
*(a + 0 * 2 * sizeof(int) + 0 * sizeof(int)) = 10
```

Al evaluar esta expresión, nos daría como resultado (seguiré con el diagrama de memoria que mostré anteriormente):

```c
0x4 + 0 + 0
0x4
```

¡Exactamente! Da como resultado la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del **array**. Esto quiere decir que el compilador no necesita usar toda esta aritmética:

```c
*(a + 0 * 2 * sizeof(int) + 0 * sizeof(int)) = 10
```

Simplemente debe traducirlo a:

```c
*(a)
```

**Nota:** En nuestro ejemplo, el identificador `a` no es un puntero y esto se debe porque no ocupa memoria. Para más información, mirar este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346699/para-que-sirven-los-arreglos-din%c3%a1micos-con-punteros/346785#346785).

Comment: ¿En la traducción a puntero `*(a + i * 2 * sizeof(int) + j * sizeof(int)) = 10`, el valor de a es 0?
¿Para la dirección [0][0] del arreglo, sería el 0 en la cadena de dirección de memoria?

Comment: Por cierto, muchas gracias :')

Comment: @AntoniodeLeón He editado la respuesta. Espero que quede claro todo :)