# ¿Cómo funciona la instrucción del bucle anidado?

Tags: c, funciones, matrices

No comprendo la instrucción del bucle anidado, por favor si alguien me puede explicar detalladamente cómo funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumaDatos(int *lista, int max1, int max2);

main() {             
    int lista[2][5]={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int *aptr_int;   
    aptr_int = lista;

    printf("La suma devuelta por sumaDatos() es= %d\n", sumaDatos(aptr_int, 2, 5)); 
    return 0;
}
    
    
int sumaDatos(int *lista, int max1, int max2){
    int i, j, suma=0;
    for(i=0; i<max1; i++)
        for(j=0; j<max2; j++)
            suma+=*(lista + i*max2 + j);
        
    return suma;
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo leer un arreglo bidimensional usando punteros? C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359665/c%c3%b3mo-leer-un-arreglo-bidimensional-usando-punteros-c)

Answer (score 0):

No es posible pasar una matriz bidimensional de `int` como `int*`. Tal programa tiene comportamiento indefinido.

Un método que funciona es:

```
int sumaDatos(int max1, int max2, int lista[max1][max2]) {
   ....     
   scanf("%d", lista[i][j]);
```

También es posible escribir

```
int sumaDatos(int lista[2][5]) {
```

pero por supuesto solamente tal dimensiones funcionarán.

---

Por cierto, `main` debe ser `int main(void)`. Tu compilador debería haberte advertido. También, debería haberte advertido sobre punteros incompatibles. Si no, necesitas actualizar tu compilador. Siempre trate las advertencias (warnings) como errores.

Comment: *Tal programa tiene comportamiento indefinido...* El programa del OP no genera un comportamiento indefinido, porque está accediendo a la matriz por medio de aritmética de puntero. Sí accedes al array de esta forma: `lista[i][j]` (asumiendo que `lista` es un puntero), ahí sí genera un comportamiento indefinido.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Hay comportamiento indefinido. `int*` no es `int[2][5]` y no es `int (*)[5]`. No son punteros compatibles y el compilador advierte sobre eso. No es legal desreferenciar un puntero que se obtuvo de un puntero incompatible.

Comment: Esta instrucción: `suma+=*(lista + i*max2 + j);` no genera un comportamiento indefinido, es totalmente válido en C acceder al array bidimensional por medio de **aritmética de puntero**. ¿Es propenso a errores? Por supuesto que lo es, el compilador advertirá por esa razón, pero eso no quiere decir que el programa del OP tenga comportamiento indefinido.

Comment: @MrDave1999 hay una discusión ahora mismo en el sitio inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63226063/detecting-array-flattening-trick-with-gcc

Comment: El comportamiento indefinido dependerá de la forma como se use la aritmética de puntero. El OP ha usado manualmente la aritmética de puntero. Mirar este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359665/c%c3%b3mo-leer-un-arreglo-bidimensional-usando-punteros-c). El OP usa la aritmética que el compilador usa para acceder al array bidimensional, eso es lo que está haciendo, por esa razón no genera un comportamiento indefinido.

Comment: Sí el OP usara una instrucción así: `lista[i]`, el compilador lo transforma a: `*(lista + i)`, ahí sí se genera comportamiento indefinido, esa no es la aritmética apropiada para acceder a un array 2D..

Comment: @MrDave1999 gracias, he visto esta pregunta y tu respuesta. En mi opinión la respuesta es incorrecta. No importa que el compilador usa el mismo algoritmo. El estándar dice que lo está permitido. No se puede decir "pero el compilador funciona de la misma manera". El compilador está permitido hacer eso, y el programador no.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Lo siento, no entiendo. OP he usado `*(lista + i*max2 + j)`. Es lo mismo que `lista[i*max2 + j]` por definición. ¿Por qué uno es bueno y el otro es malo?

Comment: La respuesta no es que sea "incorrecta", **simplemente se enfoca a responder la pregunta del OP** y al final indico que acceder a un array 2D por medio de un puntero no es recomendable ni legible. La cuestión aquí es que no es correcto decir que el código del OP tiene comportamiento indefinido cuando en realidad no lo tiene. **Él solo quiere saber como funciona esta instrucción:** `*(lista + i*max2 + j)`, nada más.

Comment: Con respecto a tu pregunta, sí, ambas sentencias hacen lo mismo y compilan perfectamente y hasta funciona. Sin embargo, no usaría ninguna de las dos para un proyecto personal o en producción. Un mal uso de la aritmética haría que se genere un comportamiento indefinido.