# error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c

Aquí esta el código, me genera el siguiente error:

> tipos no válidos 'int[int]' para subíndice de matriz.

Quiero poner la función `void transpuesta` para llamarla, y guardar un apuntador con el fin de guardar la dirección de la original e imprimirla.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void transpuesta(int *);

int main(){
    printf("###### PROGRAMA APUNTADORES ######\n");
    int *ap;
    int arr[4][4]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
    ap=&arr[0][0];
    transpuesta(ap);
}

void transpuesta(int *arrt)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
             printf("%d", *arrt[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está claro que el error está en esta expresión:

```c
*arrt[j][i]
        ^
```

Para entender este error debemos saber primero que hace el operador de indexación (`[]`). Este tipo de operador solo aplica para punteros y *arrays*.

Un operador devuelve un resultado, como el operador *suma* (`+`), que devuelve como resultado un número. Así mismo funciona el operador de indexación, devuelve como resultado un *tipo de dato*. Por ejemplo:

```c
int arr[] = {1, 2};
int* a = arr;
int b = a[1];
```

En el ejemplo anterior el operador de indexación me devuelve un *int*. Esto parece obvio pero es bueno aclararlo por si las dudas. Ahora que pasaría si escribo esto:

```c
int b = a[1][1];
```

El primer operador `[]` me devuelve `int` pero el segundo operador no me puede devolver nada porque no podemos aplicar el operador `[]` a un `int`. Recuerde la restricción: *Solo podemos aplicar el operador `[]` en punteros o arrays*.

Entonces sabiendo todo esto podemos comprender el porque del error:

```c
*arrt[j][i]
        ^
```

`arr[j]` devuelve `int` y **no podemos volver aplicar el segundo operador a un `int`.** Porque un `int` no es un puntero ni *array*.

A la final dirás, que pasaría si elimino el segundo operador `[]`:

```c
*arrt[j]
```

El error seguiría... porque no podemos aplicar el operador de desreferencia (`*`) a un `int` (recuerda que `arrt[j]` devuelve un `int`). Este operador solo aplica en punteros o *arrays*.

Hay varias soluciones para este problema, de hecho hay muchas maneras de acceder a un *array bidimensional* a través de un puntero.

**Primera forma** (su uso no es tan común):

```c
// En el Main:
ap=&arr[0][0];
transpuesta(ap); // llamar al método.

void transpuesta(int *arrt)
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
             printf("%d",  *(arrt + i* 4 + j));
        }
    }
}
```

Si quieres una explicación más profunda sobre esta expresión: `*(arrt + i* 4 + j)`, revise este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359665/c%C3%B3mo-leer-un-arreglo-bidimensional-usando-punteros-c).

**Segunda forma** (la más común):

```c
// En el Main:
transpuesta(arr); // llamar al método.

void transpuesta(int arrt[][4])
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
             printf("%d\n", arrt[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Esta forma me gusta, es la más fácil de entender y menos propenso a errores (porque no necesitas formar tu propia aritmética de punteros).

**Tercera forma:**

```c
// En el Main:
transpuesta(arr); // llamar al método.

void transpuesta(int (*arrt)[4])
{
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
         for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
             printf("%d\n", arrt[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

De hecho, la segunda y tercera forma son equivalentes (al final `arrt` es un puntero a un *array* de 4 elementos).